# Estou com problemas ao importar um arquivo em ruby

Tags: ruby

Estou tentando importar um arquivo em ruby usando o `require` e o `require_relative` mas sempre recebo este erro `Traceback (most recent call last): 1: from app.ruby:1:in` ' app.ruby:1:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- C:/xampp/htdocs/some-ruby-projects/project-10/product.ruby (LoadError)`

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

meu código

```
require_relative 'product.ruby'
require_relative 'market.ruby'

product = Product.new
market = Market.new(product)

product.price = "3.990"
product.name = "Iphone 6s"
market.buy(product)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tire a extensão .ruby e a troque por .rb e ao invés de colocar  **require_relative 'product.ruby'** e **require_relative 'market.ruby'** deixe apenas 'product' e 'market', pois além da extensão .ruby não existir não é necessário colocar qualquer extensão quando se utiliza o require_relative, pois ele vai  procurar outro arquivo através da string que foi colocada entre ''